# How to position javascript code in html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble placing the javascript code, the snake game, in the center of the screen. It just jumps down a bit, how can i fix this?

the code was too long to put here,

CSS:  https://pastebin.com/6N9H7dJd

JAVASCRIPT: https://pastebin.com/PBENS81s

I want the snake canvas to be place in the middle of the screen, not centered only in the y axel, but also in the x axel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icon/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:100,100i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <title> MOCKO </title>
  </head>

  <body>

<center>

<div id="yes">
        <h2>Score: <span id="score"></span> </h2>

        <div id="stage" style="position:relative"></div>


        <script src="snake.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var game = new Game(20, 10, "stage", "score");

        </script>
</div>

</center>

  </body>



</html>
```

Comment: "the code was too long to put here" — This is why Stackoverflow expects a [mcve] and not all the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to test out your code since I do not have access to a demo/minimal example, but theoretically speaking, we could centre the parent div that contains the snake game, as well as the score, using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

The div with the id `yes` is the parent container, whereas  the score and the div containing the snake game are the flex children.

```
<body>
  <div id="yes">
    <h2>Score: <span id="score"></span> </h2>
    <div id="stage" style="position:relative"></div>


    <script src="snake.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var game = new Game(20, 10, "stage", "score");
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
```

On your .css,

```
#yes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

The properties `justify-content` and `align-items` with the value of `center` will  center the flex children  along the line and in the cross-axis respectively, thus placing them on the centre of the page. The property `flex-direction` with the value of `column` aligns the children from  top to bottom.